# Difficulty in sendline method of pexpect module

Tags: python, pexpect

I need to automate a interview process by giving a predefined answers if I expect some string in the question of the interview.

I am using pexpect.spawn to start a child process and to go through the interview.

A portion of my code is :

```
child.expect("\> ")

child.sendline("test")
```

I am saving the interview process in a file using child.logfile=fout

A portion of fout is:

```
What would you like to use for the display name:^M
> ^M

Invalid input: ''^M

^M

What would you like to use for the display name:^M
> test


test^M
```

As seen above, it is matching a new line first time, hence the comment "Invalid input:". 
SO it asks the same question twice and then it accepts "test" as the answer.

What can I do to make my answer accepted for the very first time ?

Is there anything related to the parameter "timeout" in child.expect ?

I have tried using options such as timeout=0, timeout=-1 etc. But nothing is working.

Comment: Yes. Why are you escaping the `>`? (I don't know much python, so it might be legitimate, but `'> '` would seem more in standing with what the pexpect doc samples have.)

Comment: This time I did not escape the ">" character. I used:     child.expect("> "). But my fout looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

wow get the answer:
**child.setecho(False)**

worked on this issue for couple hours.
luckily this works.

I think the issue lies in that whenever we send a line, if the line we sent matches the pattern we epxect (like the PROMPT we generally use. ) then before the result came out
pexpect returns.

have to say we have to choose the  EXPECTING PATTERN CAREFULLY.
generally for me, I followed the recommended way in the example, setting PS1=[PEXPECT]\$ and then setecho off then send command to change the PS1
this procedure works for me.

Comment: I don't follow most of this answer, but setting `child.setecho(False)` did work for me (in allowing me to remove a redundant but necessary sendline)